# How to complete a CompletableFuture<Void>?

Tags: java, completable-future

I want a CompletableFuture that only signals the completion (e.g. I don't have a return value).

I can instantiate the CompletableFuture as:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<> ();
```

But what should I feed into the complete method? For example, I can't do

```
future.complete(new Void());
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As you've noticed, you cannot instantiate a `Void` object like this.
Since you don't care about the future's value, you could just complete it with `null`:

```
future.complete(null);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But is it saying that there is no way to instantiate Void at all? what happens if you call future.get() ? In this case I would get a null rather than a Void I assume?

Comment: @Xinchao yup, you'd get a `null`. And to quote [`Void`'s javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html): "The Void class is **an uninstantiable placeholder** class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void."

Answer (score 2):

A bit shorter (and more elegant) way to write it would be:

```
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
```